# How to convert `2020-04-06T09:04:52.610+02:00` into a `datetime.datetime` in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

> How to convert `2020-04-06T09:04:52.610+02:00` into a `datetime.datetime` in Python3?

I know that `strptime` is used to convert a `str` into a `datetime`, whereas `strftime` is used to convert a `datetime` into a `str`.

There are many examples online, like `datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005 1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')`.

My problem is the following part of the time above: `T09:04:52.610+02:00`. I can't find any sensible format code on http://strftime.org/ that matches it.

If I had a matching format code, I would write something like:

`datetime.strptime('2020-04-06T09:04:52.610+02:00', '%Y-%m-%d%X')`, where `%X` would match the `T09:04:52.610+02:00` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a date formatted as ISO format, so just go ahead and use `datetime.fromisoformat`:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.datetime.fromisoformat("2020-04-06T09:04:52.610+02:00")
datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 9, 4, 52, 610000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)))
```

---

As for `strptime`, the second argument is basically any string with some special markers in it (like `%b`). You can perfectly include any characters you want in that string, so the following works as well (although `fromisoformat` is obviously the way to go):

```
>>> dt.datetime.strptime("2020-04-06T09:04:52.610+02:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 9, 4, 52, 610000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)))
```

Comment: Thank you. There is a type in your code: `ad` should be `as`. How did you know it was an ISO formatted time? Do you have a good reference like strftime.org that lists different time formats, so I could figure this out myself?

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is (one of?) the most broadly used format to represent dates and times in CS, so you'll come across it quite often. As for other time formats, I'm not aware of other common string representations; as far as Python is concerned, the only three `from*` methods defined in `datetime.datetime` are `fromisoformat`, `fromordinal` and `fromtimestamp`.

Comment: `fromtimestamp` operates on a unix timestamp (seconds since epoch, I guess) - how would an ordinal for `fromordinal` look like?

Comment: @Shuzheng Here's [the doc about `formordinal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromordinal); looks like it's related to the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar). Though I'm no expert on that subject, it looks like `fromordinal` takes an int, and returns the corresponding date where `1` is the first of January of year 1, then `2` is the next day and so on.